# Google Checkout API, automatic default language selector?

Tags: google-checkout

Google Checkout API, automatic default language selector?

How do I select the google checkout default language? as my customers don't understand english.. so I have to set default language of Google checkout to their language..

seems in my browser it adds a GET request similar to ?hl=pt_PT to indicate language has been changed.

Unfortunately I checked the Google HTML API from start to end and found nothing related to language.

Then I thought Google was geniuses so obviously they implemented most likely some automatic language detection system, to confirm this.. I've used a Brazil proxy.. going to google.com would redirect me to google.com.br using probably some kind of geo-location database of ip addresses that access the page.

But this kind of automatic ip to language detection system doesn't exist for google checkout.. I tested, it was still in english.

Then i looked at forums and found worse news.
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/checkout-merchants/thread?tid=476957e70adc01f0&hl=en

So is there any like

`<input type="hidden" name="language" value="pt_PT"/>`

? something like that ? or no luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Checkout is localized in 19 languages for buyers.

The buyer can select their preferred language at checkout time by clicking on the drop-down in the top right corner.